# VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

```
<ScrollView>
  <Flatlist data={[1,2,3]}/>
</ScrollView>
```

Copy this code to the new react-native project which has a version of 0.64 it will fail right away

After Updating from react native 0.61 to 0.64 VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews (Error not warning) start falling as I can't just change to each and every page I need one general solution as I don't have any large flatlist inside scroll view but I can't modify each and every pages individual I just need the same working as previous react version as performance is not concerned dut to a small list

tried methods so far

1.FlatList add props = nestedScrollEnabled

2.ListHeaderComponent & ListFooterComponent (can't change due to number of pages are hight)

3.LogBox / Yellobox to hide error
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['VirtualizedLists should never be nested']);

4. Dont want to add a Map loop into the render UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your Flatlist as the entire view and take advantage of the ListHeaderComponent and ListFooterComponent parameters to add any elements that should not be scrollable. Something like:

```js
<FlatList
  ListHeaderComponent={<MyComponentGoingAboveTheList />}
  data={[{ key: "a" }, { key: "b" }]}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
  ListBottomComponent={<MyComponentGoingBelowTheList />}
/>
```